# Remove "Share this on Google+" after google share button?

Tags: google-plus

I'm using the standard share button plugin for Google+, and after the button there's a bit of text that reads "Share this on Google+":

```
<script >
    window.___gcfg = {
      lang: 'zh-CN',
      parsetags: 'onload'
    };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

I'd like to hide or remove that text, but since it's in the iFrame it's not possible to do it with CSS. I'm finding the documentation lacking or confusing on their dev pages for this share buttons.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Is there any way to remove that text?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the data-annotation attribute and set its value to none, eg:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none"></div>
```

More info here within the [share tag attributes](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharetag-parameters) of the docs.